# how to handle unix command having \x in python code

Tags: python-2.7, unix

I want to execute command

`sed -e 's/\x0//g' file.xml`

using Python code.

But getting error **ValueError: `invalid \x escape`**

Comment: Please paste your python code and sample content in file.xml.

Answer (score 1):

You are not showing your Python code, so there is room for speculation here.

But first, why does the file contain null bytes in the first place?  It is not a valid XML file.  Can you fix the process which produces this file?

Secondly, why do you want to do this with `sed`?  You are already using Python; use its native functions for this sort of processing.  If you expect to read the file line by line, something like

```
with open('file.xml', 'r') as xml:
    for line in xml:
        line = line.replace('\x00', '')
        # ... your processing here
```

or if you expect the whole file as one long byte string:

```
with open('file.xml', 'r') as handle:
    xml = handle.read()
xml = xml.replace('\x00', '')
```

If you really do want to use an external program, `tr` would be more natural than `sed`.  What syntax exactly to use depends on the dialect of `tr` or `sed` as well, but the fundamental problem is that backslashes in Python strings are interpreted by Python.  If there is a shell involved, you also need to take the shell's processing into account.  But in very simple terms, try this:

```
os.system("sed -e 's/\\x0//g' file.xml")
```

or this:

```
os.system(r"sed -e 's/\x0//g' file.xml")
```

Here, the single quotes inside the double quotes are required because a shell interprets this.  If you use another form of quoting, you need to understand the shell's behavior under that quoting mechanism, and how it interacts with Python's quoting.  But you don't really need a shell here in the first place, and I'm guessing in reality your processing probably looks more like this:

```
sed = subprocess.Popen(['sed', '-e', r's/\x0//g', 'file.xml'],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
result, err = sed.communicate()
```

Because no shell is involved here, all you need to worry about is Python's quoting.  Just like before, you can relay a literal backslash to `sed` either by doubling it, or by using a `r'...'` raw string.

Answer (score 0):

Hex escapes in Python need two hex digits.

```
\x00
```

Comment: but i want to execute only "sed -e 's/\x0//g' file.xml" which helped me to remove invalid chars from xml file. I don't need a hex.

Comment: Then you need to tell Python.

Comment: But how can i tell python??

Comment: Did you try escaping the backslash?

Comment: i tried \\x, /\x, \(x), \'x', but still its giving same error